# Setting different `PATH` variable for different profiles in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, iterm, path, macos

I have the default `PATH` variable as set in the `.zshrc` file.

I am looking for an elegant and simple way to add more directories to the `PATH` per different profiles in iTerm2.

What would be the best way to do it?

To be concrete, assume I want:

1. Add `/Users/myusername/somfolder1` and `/Users/myusername/somfolder2/bin` to path of `profile1`.
2. Add `/Users/myusername/somfolder3` to `profile2`.

Comment: Why not set the path as a command when the profile is opened?

Comment: Why not just have one path with all the search locations in it?

Comment: @Allan, the whole idea is being time efficient.

Comment: @MarcWilson, Some are different versions of the same binaries, so they can not coexist.

Comment: I get that @GeorgeIrwin.  Within the profile in the “run a command” setting , set the path variable as needed:  `PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar:/foobar/foobar…`

Comment: @Allan, I wrote as a command `export PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar:/foobar/foobar` and got error. You say just write `PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar:/foobar/foobar`  without the `export`?

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: @Allan, `export is not a valid` or something like that.

Comment: `export` just makes the variable available in subshells.  For now, just leave it off and see if the PATH get's set as you expect.

Comment: @Allan, I will give it a try. Maybe post it as an answer as well?

Answer (score 1):

I use `Terminal`, not `iTerm2`, so I don't know if there is something comparable, but in `Terminal`, the following works for `bash`:

```
cat > ~/profileForThisTerm << EOF
PATH="${PATH}:/Users/myusername/somfolder1"
```

then

- Settings
- Profiles
- Choose the profile to modify
- Shell
- Click `Run command`
- Enter `source ~/profileForThisTerm`
- Make sure `Run inside shell` is clicked

Opening a terminal window against that `Terminal` profile
You might be able to find something similar for `iTerm2` and `zsh`.

Comment: Basically create a script and run it. I will try.